# In Google Chrome, my modal window's border glitches upon transitioning in

Tags: google-chrome, css, modal-dialog, css-transitions

I have a testing page I made where I created a modal dialog for logging users in. I want to make the dialog fade in using CSS3 transitions, which I've succeeded doing, but the div's borders seem to glitch while transitioning it's opacity and some inside paragraphs seem to move around 1px. I cannot recreate the problem on jsFiddle, so here is my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Modal Testing</title>
<style type="text/css">
.popup {
    margin:auto;
    margin-left:-100px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    z-index: -1;
    position:fixed;
    background: white;
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:11pt;
    clear: both;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.popup a, .signup a {
    font-size:8pt;
}

.info {
    text-align: center;
}

.signup {
    margin:auto;
    margin-left:-100px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    background: white;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:11pt;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.alignright {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

.field {
    width: 80%;
}
</style>
<script>

function displayLogin() {
    closeSignup();
    openStyle("popup", "150px");
    document.getElementById("username").tabIndex = "1";
    document.getElementById("password").tabIndex = "2";
    document.getElementById("loginsubmitbutton").tabIndex = "3";
    document.getElementById("loginclose").tabIndex = "4";
    document.getElementById("signuplink").tabIndex = "5";
    document.getElementById("forgottenlink").tabIndex = "6";
}
function displaySignup() {
    closeLogin();
    openStyle("signup", "200px");
    document.getElementById("signup_username").tabIndex = "1";
    document.getElementById("signup_password").tabIndex = "2";
    document.getElementById("signup_reenter").tabIndex = "3";
    document.getElementById("signup_email").tabIndex = "4";
    document.getElementById("signupsubmitbutton").tabIndex = "5";
    document.getElementById("signupclose").tabIndex = "6";
}
function openStyle(classname, height) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(classname)[0].style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementsByClassName(classname)[0].style.zIndex = "10";
}
function closeLogin() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {closeStyle("popup");
    document.getElementById("username").tabIndex = "-1";
    document.getElementById("password").tabIndex = "-1";
    document.getElementById("loginsubmitbutton").tabIndex = "-1";
    document.getElementById("loginclose").tabIndex = "-1";
    document.getElementById("signuplink").tabIndex = "-1";
    document.getElementById("forgottenlink").tabIndex = "-1";}, 500);
}
function closeSignup() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("signup")[0].style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {closeStyle("signup");
    document.getElementById("signup_username").tabIndex = "-1";
    document.getElementById("signup_password").tabIndex = "-1";
    document.getElementById("signup_reenter").tabIndex = "-1";
    document.getElementById("signup_email").tabIndex = "-1";
    document.getElementById("signupsubmitbutton").tabIndex = "-1";
    document.getElementById("signupclose").tabIndex = "-1";}, 500);
}
function closeStyle(classname) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(classname)[0].style.zIndex = "-1";
}
function submitLogin() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    document.getElementById("username").value = "";
    document.getElementById("password").value = "";
    //submit login as POST request from XMLHTTPrequest
}
function submitSignup() {
    var username = document.getElementById("signup_username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("signup_password").value;
    var reenter = document.getElementById("signup_reenter").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("signup_email").value;
    if (password !== reenter) {
        alert("The passwords do not match.");
        return;
    }
    //submit signup as POST request from XMLHTTPrequest
    console.log({user:username, pass:password, email:email});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="displayLogin();">Show Login Screen</button><br>
<div class="popup">
    Username:<a class="alignright" href="javascript:closeLogin();" id="loginclose" tabIndex="-1">close</a><br>
    <input type="text" id="username" class="field" tabIndex="-1" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('loginsubmitbutton').click()"><br>
    Password:<br>
    <input type="password" id="password" class="field" tabIndex="-1" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('loginsubmitbutton').click()"><br>
    <button onclick="submitLogin();" id="loginsubmitbutton" tabIndex="-1">Login</button><br>
    <p class="info"><a href="javascript:displaySignup();" id="signuplink" tabIndex="-1" >Sign up!</a> - <a href="javascript:displayForgotten();" id="forgottenlink" tabIndex="-1">Forgot Password?</a></p>
</div>
<div class="signup">
    Username:<a class="alignright" href="javascript:closeSignup();" id="signupclose" tabIndex="-1">close</a><br>
    <input type="text" id="signup_username" class="field" tabIndex="-1" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('signupsubmitbutton').click()"><br>
    Password:<br>
    <input type="password" id="signup_password" class="field" tabIndex="-1" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('signupsubmitbutton').click()"><br>
    Re-enter Password:<br>
    <input type="password" id="signup_reenter" class="field" tabIndex="-1" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('signupsubmitbutton').click()"><br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" id="signup_email" class="field" tabIndex="-1" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('signupsubmitbutton').click()"><br>
    <button onclick="submitSignup();" id="signupsubmitbutton" tabIndex="-1">Signup</button><br><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please excuse my bad habits.